# Accessing variables in build.gradle's section plugins

Tags: gradle

I want to use variables in section Plugins (from gradle.properties)

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'eclipse-wtp'
    id "com.moowork.grunt" version $grunt_version
    id "org.akhikhl.gretty" version $gretty_version
}
```

but this won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `project.grunt_version`?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By digging deeper in the gradle docs I found this:

> The form is:
>
> ```
> plugins {
>     id «plugin id» version «plugin version»
> }
> ```
>
> Where «plugin version» and «plugin id» must be constant, literal, strings. No other statements are allowed; their presence will cause a compilation error.
>
> The plugins {} block must also be a top level statement in the
>   buildscript. It cannot be nested inside another construct (e.g. an
>   if-statement or for-loop).

...

> If the restrictions of the new syntax are prohibitive, the recommended approach is to apply plugins using the buildscript {} block.

I think I'll give it a try...

Comment: When I tried to wrap my plugins block with a buildscript block, I get "Could not find method plugins()". Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, dollars are only used inside double quoted strings, to expand a variable name to its value. Like Opal indicates in their comment, you can call a variable by simply its name in most places. Depending on the variable's scope, it may be appropriate to call it as `variableName`, `project.variableName`, etc, depending on which object the variable belongs to.

For instance:

```
def foo = "boo"
```

The following two are equivalent:

```
def moreOos = foo + "ooo"
def alsoMoreOos = "${foo}ooo"
```